# Iterable<Iterable<T>> cannot confirm generic T in function

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

Here is my problem.

```
const iterable = [[[1,2,3]]]
function flat<T>(t:Iterable<Iterable<T>>):Iterable<T>{
    return [...t][0]
}
const flatted = flat(iterable) //return Iterable<unknown>
```

above function cannot suppose T as number, just assert it as unknown.
At this momemt, I tought that 'hmm... generic in generic cannot be infered?'. But below code chuck works well

```
const iterable = [[[1,2,3]]]
function flat<T>(t:Array<Array<T>>):Array<T>{
    return [...t][0]
}
const flatted = flat(iterable) // omg.. return Array<number>
```

also

```
const iterable = [[[1,2,3]]]
function flat<T>(t:Iterable<Array<T>>):Array<T>{
    return [...t][0]
}
const flatted = flat(iterable) // also works.. return Array<number>
```

What are differences between those? 
Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Could be that TypeScript inference just has better support for unwrapping nested arrays? Note that `Array<Array<T>>` is identical to `T[][]` in TypeScript, and `flatted` is actually `number[][]`, not `number[]`

Comment: Sorry, lack of my explanation, I will add more. nested Array seems to be inferd only. `Iterable<Array<Iterable<T>>>` also can infer 
  `number[][][]` as number

Comment: I can not make a statement with arguments, so accept it as an opinionated, but IMHO TypeScript has some issues with generics and inferring types from them. I had experience the same you have, where it is obviously can infer the type but it can not. Looks like a poor implementation or bugs, IDK.

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov, Thanks for your reply. If it might true, omg.. I hope there is solution in somewhere.

Comment: In such situation I just pass the type parameter explicitly where it need to

Comment: That works, Thanks for your sincere reply. @EugeneObrezkov

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yuck, yeah, I see that the default inference doesn't work deeply enough to unroll `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` into `T`.  It's not *that* surprising if you look at how  the typings for `Iterable` are [defined in the relevant library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L50-L52):

```
interface Iterable<T> {
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T>;
}
```

An `Iterable<T>` has a symbol-keyed method whose return type is `Iterator<T>`, which itself is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L43-L48) as:

```
interface Iterator<T, TReturn = any, TNext = undefined> {
    next(...args: [] | [TNext]): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
    return?(value?: TReturn): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
    throw?(e?: any): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
}
```

where all the methods return `IteratorResult<T, ...>`, which is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L41) to be a discriminated union type

```
type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
```

whose [members](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L31-L39) are

```
interface IteratorYieldResult<TYield> {
    done?: false;
    value: TYield;
}

interface IteratorReturnResult<TReturn> {
    done: true;
    value: TReturn;
}
```

of which only one has a `value` property of the relevant type `T` you're trying to find.

So to turn a type `X` of `Iterable<T>` into `T`, the compiler needs to do something like `Extract<ReturnType<ReturnType<X[typeof Symbol.iterator]>['next']>, { done?: false }>['value']`.

I think there's probably some depth limit after which the compiler gives up trying to infer things.  You can see that inferring `T` from `Iterable<T>` works (maybe about 5 or 6 layers of nesting), but inferring `T` from `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` is just too deep (10 or 12 layers?):

```
type N = number[][] extends Iterable<infer T> ? T : never; // number[] 
type O = number[][] extends Iterable<Iterable<infer T>> ? T : never; // unknown
```

---

That leads me to the following workaround: make a type alias to explicitly operate on one layer of `Iterable`, and then use that twice:

```
type DeIterable<T extends Iterable<any>> = T extends Iterable<infer U> ? U : never;
```

You can see this works:

```
type Okay = DeIterable<DeIterable<number[][]>>; // number
```

And now `flat()` can be defined like this:

```
function flat<II extends Iterable<Iterable<any>>>(
  t: II
): Iterable<DeIterable<DeIterable<II>>> {
  return [...t][0]
}
```

Where the input value is the generic type `II`, and we use `DeIterable` on it twice to get the `T` you wanted before:

```
const flatted = flat(iterable) //return Iterable<number[]>
```

Looks good, now!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAclC8UB2BXAtgIwgJwNoF0CoIAPYCJAEwGcoBJc7AQwwBsIAeASyQDMcoAFQB8UAPxCoALmQQAbjgDcUAPQrk6LHnxRAvBuBZHYBQoSFADyCDZhwEipclVoMcLdh2fM2nHv2xDhohKC0rIK2MpqUChIANZIAPYA7kh6gHI7hhkm0AAiEB6unMH2FDT0jAUcTEggAZZFZCVO5V7cfAIAqoFQ7SFI8kqZ4NBmMUwglrn5LZPNbqjW2gQBEerzWnpGhgDG8UjUwFBcs9CIuGcAjAA0UABM1wDM+E8ZvNFbwFy7ULysTMDudGIDUcZRcLSmbiqNQCAApDFAoMAZHQ6IYAJTI44cGZgtw4zxuFEBUQAb3hUGwEGAKGwKVwADpGcBCAAGfCGAC+212+2+v2A5Eolh+fxhR1xEDRqhUlOptNBBM4axs+FEUAyhiAA)