# Typescript can't infer inner type of Iterable of Iterable

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array, nested, typescript-generics, type-inference

Here is a simple function that takes in an Iterable of Iterables.

```
function unwrapFirst<T extends Iterable<U>, U>(iter: Iterable<T>): U {
  return [...[...iter][0]][0];
}

unwrapFirst([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]);
```

I expected TypeScript to infer the type of `U` correctly as `number` but it infers it as `unknown`. Can someone explain why? And how to get TypeScript to correctly infer `U`?

Comment: Weird, `function unwrapFirst<U>(iter: Iterable<U>): U { return [...iter][0]; }; unwrapFirst([1,2,3]);` does get inferred correctly to `function unwrapFirst<number>(iter: Iterable<number>): number`, but `function unwrapFirst<U, T extends Iterable<U>>(iter: T): U { return [...iter][0]; }; unwrapFirst([1,2,3]);` does not, and instead infers to `function unwrapFirst<unknown, number[]>(iter: number[]): unknown`.

Comment: A performance note: you should use `return iter[Symbol.iterator]().next().value[Symbol.iterator]().next().value;` as the body of the function to avoid iterating the entire nested sequence just to get the first value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) are not used as inference sites.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#44711](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44711) for a similar issue.

You were presumably expecting the compiler to infer `U` from `T` given that `T` is constrained to `Iterable<U>`.  But that does not happen because constraints are not used as inference sites.  So the type inferred for `T` has no effect on `U`, and therefore `U` fails to be inferred and the compiler [falls back to `unknown`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown).

If you want to use inference to get `U` from `T`, you will make the function generic in only `T`, and then calculate `U` via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types). For example:

```
function unwrapFirst<T extends Iterable<any>>(
    iter: Iterable<T>
): T extends Iterable<infer U> ? U : never {
    return [...[...iter][0]][0];
}

const res = unwrapFirst([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
// const res: number
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAkgdwE4EMAOAxODAZxgB4AVZAUwA8YqIATI5ASXuwCMAbK0rCAE8AfMIAUwZFORwOALjYcsPPuWHAAlAsq16TFuypdepOBBBHkAVWHIA-NeQKIVAG6WA3pOkYqMMBgoANoAdGGhYbJGALpBAAzRsQkA3MAAvsDAUEgkyL4sALyoEJi4BMQwYkFBAIwANMgATA0AzNENQQAsDQCsDQBsiRqp0sgA9GPI2RC5+c5gALacRplAA)

Comment: Man, I was reading an old answer of yours on a close subject (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506176/iterableiterablet-cannot-confirm-generic-t-in-function), I'm impressed with your knownledge, thanks for sharing it !

Comment: I'm also impressed. I swear if it wasn't for jcalz's answers I think I'd still be trying to figure out how to tie my shoes.

Comment: It is interesting that the simpler version `unwrapFirst<T>(iter: Iterable<Iterable<T>>): T` does not work, but it `iter:T[][]` does infer correctly. And even extracting `Iterable<Iterable<infer U>>` from `number[][]` does work in conditional types.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=30&pln=22&pc=57#code/N4WAUABBBmCuB2BjALgSwPbwgg7gJwEMAHAMVTwGdkAeAFQD4AKVZAUzwC4IBJNwgIwA2rar3YEhIhvQCUXWhFCQoKvK2Sw8WANoA6fXv0t2AXW0AGE2csBucFAC+4exESYqENRQgBebPHxiMkpkRm1tAEYAGggAJhiAZhMY7QAWGIBWGIA2Kxk7MCcwJSg4JDRMf0DScio6JhcVCGNOCFptMxMXOTbFRtV1TR19XUNdFusrCxMCx2dlN3gPL18qwhqQsMiY+IgklPSILIhck3zwIvnkAE8iVjaI1fhYAFt+dg6OiFYADzZ4AAm3jEAmE1FQ8Gg7AgAFV6BAAPwQfow75-ViA4F8CRgiFQvCw2LwpEw2IQLjwVgAN3YFOp7Cut3utDJfmebw+nTR-yBPGxklE-NxkOhcPoJLpNLwNiAA