# TypeScript: inference for `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` is worse than for `Array<Iterable<T>>`

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/PTAEHkDsBsE9QCYEsBmKCmAndkDG7QAjdAFwHd0dRcB7PAQxIEZR7IFq7dGAmUJAM6gSACwL1MAcwCuAWxwlhsAA7oAdACgE6XNAkEU0vCSR1ODZgB4AKgD4AFEhIAuUAEFMmerEsBJElj0hNDoNra2AJSu-oHBoXYA3Fo6etighsamkObcJDxhji6gMV5xfgGlIWGR0RVBVYkaGiQqBAAKNEiQigC8oADeAB6ukHLEmAA0oLAjY1gAvkkatJACivSuHl4+HV0ktqB9ANoAuksgOYwsZDSYANZC9ELog6q4AQjLdGuggyx9K1yTHsR3oU3oJwiSRWP1gTFqsSqu26Bz6f3OYEBvEQNHQQkgNBIX1WikGfABXF4ILBrEhCVAFy6GE86A4T2KdTKRjuBLIkFsxNhPARlVCyP2h1+PHpF2sAGVQABRABKyvAytc1laoAA5CV6qFubz+Tr+PjCawBAIkJJIAbhDQlKpdfqyuLbDrNBoLli8qABJRZEISI6bvdQGQxNkKKBlJgaAA3JDaVjZF5vD5Ogy3YRiUDp7BWrKaGGkgDMIoNlndkt9PGp4LpgsUsArHMRYs6KMlgzLSSAA)

```js
// Only difference between concat1 and concat2 is the argument type.
declare function concat1<T>(it: Array<Iterable<T>>): Iterable<T>;
declare function concat2<T>(it: Iterable<Iterable<T>>): Iterable<T>;

type Point = {x: number, y: number};

const a: Array<Point> = [];

// concat1 works as expected
const x1 = concat1([a, a]);
const y1: Iterable<Point> = x1;

// concat2 does not
const x2 = concat2([a, a]); // inferred as Iterable<unknown>
const y2: Iterable<Point> = x2; // TS ERROR: Type 'Iterable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<Point>'.

// concat2 seems to work when we provide an expected type for the expression.
const x3: Iterable<Point> = concat2([a, a]);
const y3: Iterable<Point> = x3;
```

Comment: I don't see a question here, but the issue is the same one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61506176/2887218), so I'm going to close this as a duplicate of that.  You can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nledem) to get the desired behavior.