# Why does this flatten function cause unknown to be included in the return type?

Tags: typescript

Why is the type of the return value here `Set<unknown>` instead of `Set<number>`? I'm able to nudge it into the expected type with an annotation, but I'm surprised that's necessary.

```
export function flatten<T>(iterable: Iterable<Iterable<T>>): Set<T> {
  const result = new Set<T>();
  for (const iter of iterable) {
    for (const val of iter) {
      result.add(val);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const foo = flatten([[1, 2, 3]]); // Why is the type of foo Set<unknown> instead of Set<number>?
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWIDYCGMMwKAPACoB8AFJiVAQEZ7ABccAkg862d8EYtglKlQCUHAMrAYouAG8AUHDhocAZ3hRgGpHngBeOCmAB3ODLnUa4gNwrE0ODXUotceoLgQEnnsLiio6qCM6umvAAbgR4Pn5eUEHKqqlwOnoGAHQEACa5NDF49iFwAL6OFao6MEhQuBn6MA4VSm4eYRBwxgiExKQ0ANqDAIwANHAATBMAzAC6c-ZwAPTLcADqABYAnp4acDCbwAfbYMe+Tl1WZKgA1igQZihUnu4kefGWsmQoSAC2TEEVAA-EA)

Comment: Yeah, this is a pain point; see [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61507516/2887218) for more info