# TypeScript Conditional Types - How to get nested type (of Iterable) correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, conditional-types

I want to define a type `GoodNestedIterableType` that will convert something from `Iterable<Iterable<A>>` to `A`.

So If I had the following code

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
]

type GoodNestedIterableType<A> = A extends Iterable<infer B> 
  ? B extends Iterable<infer C>
    ? C : never
  : never
type GoodExtractedType = GoodNestedIterableType<typeof arr> // number

type BadNestedIterableType<A> = A extends Iterable<Iterable<infer B>>
  ? B
  : never
type BadExtractedType = BadNestedIterableType<typeof arr> // unknown
```

`GoodExtractedType` correctly types to `number`, while `BadExtractedType` incorrectly (or I should say unexpectedly) types to `unknown`.

Doing the below also works correctly, when I expected it not to.

```js
BadNestedIterableType<Iterable<Iterable<number>> // number
```

Can someone help me understand the mechanics of this behavior? (even beyond `Iterable`s)

Comment: I don't have good enough explanation (might be because TS does not support higher kinded types), but I think you can use recursive approach: `type Recursive<A> = A extends Iterable<infer B> ? Recursive<B> : A;`

Comment: I looked into this before and it's mostly that the structural dependence of `Iterable<T>` on `T` is complicated, and the inference algorithm bails out before it can get `T` from `Iterable<Iterable<T>>`.  See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506176/iterableiterablet-cannot-confirm-generic-t-in-function) and its answer for more information.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use this with arrays, just use the builtin `[].flat` or `FlatArray` type

```
interface Array<T> {
    /**
     * Returns a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the
     * specified depth.
     *
     * @param depth The maximum recursion depth
     */
    flat<A, D extends number = 1>(
        this: A,
        depth?: D
    ): FlatArray<A, D>[]
}

type FlatArray<Arr, Depth extends number> = {
    "done": Arr,
    "recur": Arr extends ReadonlyArray<infer InnerArr>
        ? FlatArray<InnerArr, [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20][Depth]>
        : Arr
}[Depth extends -1 ? "done" : "recur"];
```

---

Type inference is difficult, so I guess this is just not implemented for simplicity and because noone asked